# Should i use threads when executing action method through AJAX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a questionnarie. When a user clicks on an answer possibility for a multiple choice question (this is a radio button), i call an action method to save this answer.

The code:

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.MCQRadio').click(function () {

        var question_id = $(this).attr('question-id');
        var mcq_id = $(this).attr('mcq-id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/SaveSurveyAnswers/SaveMCQAnswer',
            data: { "mcq_id": mcq_id, "question_id": question_id },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code to save the answer:

```
public EmptyResult SaveMCQAnswer(int mcq_id, int question_id)
    {
        MCQ_Answers mcqa = null;
        try
        {
            mcqa = db.MCQ_Answers.Single(x => x.question_ID == question_id);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {

        }
        if (mcqa != null)
        {
            mcqa.mcq_id = mcq_id;
        }
        else
        {
            MCQ_Answers mcq_answer = new MCQ_Answers()
            {
                question_ID = question_id,
                respondent_id = 1
            };

            db.MCQ_Answers.AddObject(mcq_answer);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

If a question has 5 answer possibilities, and i click on them randomly and fast, and then go back to the previous page, ie, when i return the correct answer wont be saved. Should i use threading to make sure the correct answer is saved? And how?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're actually doing a *load* on the previous page (you can check with the debugger). A lot of browsers try to save form values across navigation events which can cause issues in test cases like this.

Comment: I have just tested this. When i use the browsers Back button, the ActionMethod does not get called. When i click on a "go back" link which i provide, it get's called. Nonetheless, when i switch between the answer possibilties fast and go back either way, sometimes they dont get saved correctly.

Comment: In this case the question becomes: is the save method being called each time? Even if that's the case, it's possible that it's being saved AFTER you request the latest answers. None of these problems will be fixed by threading though. As an MVC application, all the requests are serviced on their own thread...

Comment: What should i do to ensure all the answers get saved correctly?

Answer (score 0):

rather than saving your answer by post all the time, you can just create a JSOn object and save the answers within json.   you can then at the end post all completed answers in one go.

take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff962533

basically this will allow you to store session data - json  on the remote machine  you then just need an add, delete  function and away you go....

i use this to huge extent in an application that would require the server to be updated with the location of objects on a canvas, however with sessvars i just keep all the X and Y locations within there and do a final push of JSON when i am done.

if you change pages, you can then get your values from the JSON object without a server call.

as a note you may also be better off with tabs or hiden sections of form, and therfor reduce the need to re-populate say  page1, page2  etc as they will already be there, just hidden!

Comment: oh and as a note, the sessvars stay, so even if they navgate away from the quiz and come back later, you can re-populate the answers... very nice

Comment: There is no final push button. My boss wants it to be saved automatically. What do you do, if the user does not complete the whole survey?

Comment: You could set a timer, say every 5 mins auto save, that way you get best of both worlds and saving of partial content!